# How to limit folder permission by ip with one user account?

Tags: ftp, network-attached-storage

My question is :

there has a user, he has the permission to visit the folder A. But :

In ip1,for example, his permission is read and write.

In ip2,his permission is readonly.

I was used to use FTP , but it must to create two user account.

I also tried NAS, but it still cann't satisfied my need.

Does there any software can satisfied my need?

My FTP software is Serv-U. My NAS platform is Synology 16180xs+，its system is DSM.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to look for an FTP daemon which is able to do it for you, or go with a different protocol (WebDAV for example, which you could serve with Apache, which has the controls you need)

Comment: Thank asdmin!, I have thought to use any other protocol. But other teams has a lot scripts to use ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the [documentation](http://www.serv-u.com/serv-u-administrator-guide.pdf) there seems to be ways to allow/disallow access based on IP, as per usual, but this is pure access to server. Once access has been given, user-permissions control what can be done, and I can't see any "conditional rules" type of feature affecting user-permissions.

It looks like it can't be done within the constraints of the software. You should use two accounts and try to work with that, it's how it is meant to be done.

One account = one set of permissions, regardless.

Comment: Thanks！ Serv-U can't satisfied my need. I has been testing the Proftp.Its function is more powerful. and it can limit the foler permissions with one account. But I stucked in the AD module...